# How to configure cors on keycloak and nginx?

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, keycloak

The problem is this: we have released an application with a Vue front-end and a keycloak authorization server. Keycloak works in a docker containerThe application is located at the URL: app.xxxx.xx, and the authorization is at the URL: auth.xxxx.xx. Nginx is used as a proxy server. Everything starts, but after authorization, the application itself does not load and an error occurs:

> > Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://auth.xxxx.xx/auth/realms/Atlas/protocol/openid-connect/token' (redirected from 'http://auth.xxxx.xx/auth/realms/Atlas/protocol/openid-connect/token') from origin 'http://app.gxxxx.xx.' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

[Keycloak config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrS8O.png)

[Nginx config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btlrB.png)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try using "+" in "Web origins" in your client configuration ?

See [Web origins](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#oidc-clients).